# Measurement in QM - positivity criterion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

Let me describe my understanding of measurements in quantum mechanics before getting to the part that I'm unclear about.

If we have a quantum state $\rho$ and we do a projective measurement in some basis, then our measurement can be described in the following way. We have a set of measurement elements $\{F_i\}$ where each $F_i = M^\dagger_i M_i =  \vert i\rangle\langle i\vert$. The measurement elements are clearly positive and Hermitian and we also have that $\sum_i F_i = I$.

Moving onto POVMs, the difference now is that we don't require that the $F_i$ satisfy orthogonality. However, do they still need to be positive operators? In my textbook, this condition is not asked for. As long as $\sum_i F_i = I$, it is a valid measurement.

In contrast, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM), it is stated that a POVM is

> ... a measure whose values are non-negative self-adjoint operators on
>   a Hilbert space..

yet [later on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM#Post-measurement_state) in the same article, when talking about POVMs seen as the system coupled to an ancilla with projective measurements, it says

> The operators of the resulting POVM are given by $F_i = M^\dagger_iM_i$. Since the $M_i$ are not required to be positive...

Does it mean that $F_i$ is still positive even if the $M_i$ are not? And if yes, how does one show this? I can see that $M^\dagger_i M_i$ is Hermitian so it has real eigenvalues but I cannot see why it should have positive eigenvalues.

I would appreciate it very much if someone could clarify what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the last part first: If $F_i=M_i^\dagger M_i$, it is automatically positive, as it is hermitian and $\langle \phi|F_i|\phi\rangle = \langle \phi|M_i^\dagger M_i|\phi\rangle=(M_i|\phi\rangle)^\dagger (M_i|\phi\rangle) \ge 0$.

---

As to the first part: The basic idea for general measurements is that probabilities should be given by linear operators on $\rho$ (otherwise the whole ensemble interpretation breaks down),
$$
p_i = \mathrm{tr}[F_i\rho]\ .
$$

Now first, it is easy to see that you can choose $F_i$ hermitian: Since $\rho$ is hermitian and $\mathrm{tr}[F_i\rho]\in\mathbb R$, $\mathrm{tr}[F_i\rho]=\mathrm{tr}[F_i^\dagger\rho]$, and we can replace $F_i$ by $\tfrac12(F_i+F_i^\dagger)$.

Second, since $\sum p_i=1$, it follows that $\sum F_i=\mathrm{Id}$.

Finally, if $F_i$ were not positive, there would be a $|\phi\rangle$ such that
$\langle \phi|F_i|\phi\rangle<0$. Then, with $\rho=|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$, it follows that
$$
p_i = \mathrm{tr}[F_i\rho]= \mathrm{tr}[F_i |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|]<0\ ,
$$
which is impossible and thus, $F_i$ must be positive semidefinite.

Comment: "Since $\rho$ is Hermitian, only the Hermitian part of $F_i$ contributes". Do you say this because you know that $p_i$ is a probability and hence real or is there some other reason?

Comment: @user1936752 Hm, you are right, it is indeed because it is real, which implies $tr(\rho F)=tr(\rho F^\dagger)$. Thanks.